# Why is Excel Crashing with Automation Error?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, automation

this is my first post, so if I do it wrong, please don't crucify me.

I have this code I've written that opens a series of workbooks (the number of workbooks it opens depends on the number of clinics in that country, up to 200 of them), and then copies any issue data from the workbook into the macro workbook. It then takes all the issues it's tracked, and copies them into another workbook and saves it as an issue log. As it runs through, at some random point, I'm getting an Automation Error that crashes excel entirely. I don't get to break on the error line. I don't get any interaction or other warning and the Automation Error does not have an error code, just Automation Error with "OK", and "Help" buttons. The help button does nothing for me. I've tried putting in timers to let the workbooks open. I've tried disabling macros that may run when the workbooks are opened to speed them up. I've tried stepping through but that doesn't produce the error, so it's only when it's running at full tilt.

I've read that these errors are caused by VBA not being able to reference the workbook object because it's not fully "open" by the time an object associated with the workbook is called, hence the timing and macro-killing code being added in, but to no avail.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? This is for work and I need this reporting to operate properly. Thanks to anyone willing to give a hand ahead of time.

Here's the code that pulls the issues from the workbooks:

````
Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Sub GetIssues()

    Dim country As String, checkPer As String, CheckMon As String, fiscYear As String, fPath As String, openFile As String, openName As String, clerk As String
    Dim company As Integer, i As Integer, clinic As Integer, checkMonDays As Integer, last As Integer, b As Integer, tableRow As Integer
    Dim setupWS As Worksheet, checkWS As Worksheet, issueWS As Worksheet, valueWS As Worksheet, metaWS As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim checkWB As Workbook
    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim listObj As ListObject
    Dim issueWSfile As Range, valueWSfile As Range, checkWSRng As Range, checkWSRng2 As Range, dateRange As Range, cell As Range, tableRng As Range, tableRng2 As Range
    Dim startDate As Date, Timer As Date, StartTime As Date, EndTime As Date
    Dim NowTick As Long, EndTick As Long

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    'previousSecurity = Application.AutomationSecurity
    'Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable

    StartTime = TimeValue(Time)

    Set setupWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup")
    Set metaWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Meta Data")
    Set issueWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Issues")
    Set valueWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values")
    Set dateRange = issueWS.Range("F1:AL1")

    last = metaWS.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    startDate = DateValue(setupWS.Range("F4").Value)

    Set issueWSfile = issueWS.Range("A2:A" & last)
    Set valueWSfile = valueWS.Range("A2:A" & last)

    issueWS.Range("A2:AK1000,F1:AJ1").ClearContents
    valueWS.Range("A2:AK1000,F1:AJ1").ClearContents
    dateRange.ClearContents

    fPath = Left(ThisWorkbook.Path, Len(ThisWorkbook.Path) - Len("Takings Control Recs"))

    checkPer = Trim(Right(GetIssForm.ComboBox2.Value, 3))
    fiscYear = Left(GetIssForm.ComboBox2.Value, 4)

    If checkPer = "P1" Then
        CheckMon = "Oct"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P2" Then
        CheckMon = "Nov"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P3" Then
        CheckMon = "Dec"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P4" Then
        CheckMon = "Jan"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P5" Then
        CheckMon = "Feb"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P6" Then
        CheckMon = "Mar"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P7" Then
        CheckMon = "Apr"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P8" Then
        CheckMon = "May"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P9" Then
        CheckMon = "Jun"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P10" Then
        CheckMon = "Jul"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P11" Then
        CheckMon = "Aug"
    ElseIf checkPer = "P12" Then
        CheckMon = "Sep"
    End If

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    setupWS.Range("F1").Value = checkPer
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    If CheckMon = "Jan" Or CheckMon = "Mar" Or CheckMon = "May" Or CheckMon = "Jul" Or CheckMon = "Aug" Or CheckMon = "Oct" Or CheckMon = "Dec" Then
        checkMonDays = 31
    ElseIf CheckMon = "Apr" Or CheckMon = "Jun" Or CheckMon = "Sep" Or CheckMon = "Nov" Then
        checkMonDays = 30
    Else: checkMonDays = 28
    End If

    For b = 1 To checkMonDays
        issueWS.Cells(1, b + 5).Value = startDate
        valueWS.Cells(1, b + 5).Value = startDate
        startDate = startDate + 1
    Next b

    country = GetIssForm.ComboBox3.Value

    'Unload GetIssForm

    For i = 5 To last
        If metaWS.Range("H" & i).Value = country Then
            company = metaWS.Range("D" & i).Value
            clinic = metaWS.Range("B" & i).Value
            clerk = metaWS.Range("F" & i).Value
            openFile = fPath & country & "\" & fiscYear & "\" & checkPer & "\E " & company & "\" & clinic & " " & checkPer & " " & CheckMon & ".xlsb"
            If Dir(openFile) <> "" Then
                openName = fso.getfilename(openFile)
                Set checkWB = Workbooks.Open(openFile)
                'EndTick = GetTickCount + 500
                'Do
                 '   NowTick = GetTickCount
                  '  DoEvents
                'Loop Until NowTick > EndTick
                Set checkWS = checkWB.Sheets("Transaction Hub")
                Set checkWSRng = checkWS.Range("AX11:AX41")
                Set checkWSRng2 = checkWS.Range("AU11:AU41")
                issueWS.Range("A" & i - 3).Value = openFile
                issueWS.Range("B" & i - 3).Value = company
                issueWS.Range("C" & i - 3).Value = clinic
                issueWS.Range("D" & i - 3).Value = clerk
                issueWS.Range("E" & i - 3).Value = country
                valueWS.Range("A" & i - 3).Value = openFile
                valueWS.Range("B" & i - 3).Value = company
                valueWS.Range("C" & i - 3).Value = clinic
                valueWS.Range("D" & i - 3).Value = clerk
                valueWS.Range("E" & i - 3).Value = country
                checkWSRng.Copy
                issueWS.Range("F" & i - 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, , True
                checkWSRng2.Copy
                valueWS.Range("F" & i - 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, , True
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Workbooks(openName).Close False
                Set checkWB = Nothing
            Else: End If
        End If
    Next i

    last = issueWS.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set listObj = issueWS.ListObjects(1)

    listObj.Resize Range("A1:AJ" & last)

    Set listObj = valueWS.ListObjects(1)

    listObj.Resize Range("A1:AJ" & last)

    Set tableRng = issueWS.ListObjects("Table2").Range
    Set tableRng2 = valueWS.ListObjects("Table1").Range

    issueWS.Activate

    For tableRow = tableRng.Row + tableRng.Rows.count - 1 To tableRng.Row Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(tableRow)) = 0 Then Rows(tableRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

    valueWS.Activate

    For tableRow = tableRng2.Row + tableRng2.Rows.count - 1 To tableRng2.Row Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(tableRow)) = 0 Then Rows(tableRow).EntireRow.Delete
    Next

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        Range("A1").Select
    Next ws

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Run").Activate

    issueWS.Range("B:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    valueWS.Range("B:D").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    'Application.AutomationSecurity = previousSecurity

    EndTime = TimeValue(Time)

    Timer = Format(EndTime - StartTime, "hh:mm:ss")

    'MsgBox "Finished in " & -Timer & " seconds", vbOKOnly, "Workbooks Created -"

    Call ReportIssues

End Sub```

And here's the code that creates the issue log:

```Option Explicit

Sub ReportIssues()

    Dim ARow As Long, issuesLastRow As Long, ACol As Long, issuesLastCol As Long, IRow As Long, issuesLastRow2 As Long, issuesLastCol2 As Long
    Dim DateNum As String, Month As String, Year As String, country As String, TestStr As String, answer As String, fPath As String
    Dim issuesWB As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet, issuesWS As Worksheet, valuesWS As Worksheet, dataWS As Worksheet, setupWS As Worksheet
    Dim count As Integer

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set dataWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Issues")
    Set setupWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup")
    Set valuesWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Values")

    dataWS.Activate

    fPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Issue Logs\"
    Debug.Print fPath
    issuesLastRow = dataWS.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    issuesLastCol = dataWS.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    issuesLastRow2 = valuesWS.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    issuesLastCol2 = valuesWS.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    IRow = 3
    DateNum = Replace(setupWS.Range("D2"), "/", "")
    count = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    country = GetIssForm.ComboBox3.Value

    Unload GetIssForm

    Set issuesWB = Workbooks.Open("Z:\Finance\HO European Transformation\15.SSC\Q Track\Build\Issues Sheet Temp.xlsb")
    Set issuesWS = issuesWB.Sheets("Issues")

    dataWS.ListObjects("Table2").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=country

    valuesWS.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=country

    If Dir(fPath & country & " " & DateNum & ".xlsb") = "" Then
here:
        For ACol = 6 To issuesLastCol
            For ARow = 2 To issuesLastRow
                If Not IsError(dataWS.Cells(ARow, ACol)) And dataWS.Cells(ARow, ACol) <> 0 And dataWS.Cells(ARow, ACol) <> "" And Len(dataWS.Cells(ARow, ACol)) > 5 And dataWS.Cells(ARow, 5) = country Then 'And dataWS.Cells(1, ACol) < setupWS.Range("D2") Then 'And dataWS.Cells(1, ACol) > setupWS.Range("F4") - 1 Then
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 1) = dataWS.Cells(1, ACol)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 2) = dataWS.Cells(ARow, 5)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 3) = dataWS.Cells(ARow, 3)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 4) = dataWS.Cells(ARow, 2)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 5) = dataWS.Cells(ARow, ACol)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 6) = valuesWS.Cells(ARow, ACol)
                    IRow = IRow + 1
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next ARow
            ARow = 2
        Next ACol
        If count = 0 Then
        For ACol = 6 To issuesLastCol2
            For ARow = 2 To issuesLastRow2
                If Not IsError(valuesWS.Cells(ARow, ACol)) And valuesWS.Cells(ARow, ACol) <> 0 And valuesWS.Cells(ARow, ACol) <> "" And valuesWS.Cells(ARow, 5) = country Then 'And dataWS.Cells(1, ACol) < setupWS.Range("D2") Then 'And dataWS.Cells(1, ACol) > setupWS.Range("F4") - 1 Then
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 1) = dataWS.Cells(1, ACol)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 2) = dataWS.Cells(ARow, 5)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 3) = dataWS.Cells(ARow, 3)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 4) = dataWS.Cells(ARow, 2)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 5) = dataWS.Cells(ARow, ACol)
                    issuesWS.Cells(IRow, 6) = valuesWS.Cells(ARow, ACol)
                    IRow = IRow + 1
                    count = count + 1
                End If
            Next ARow
            ARow = 2
        Next ACol
        End If
        With issuesWB
            .SaveAs fPath & country & " " & DateNum & ".xlsb"
            .Activate
            .Close False
        End With
        MsgBox country & " Issue Sheet saved to Issue Log folder.", vbOKOnly, "File Saved -"
    ElseIf Dir(fPath & country & " " & DateNum & ".xlsb") <> "" Then
        answer = MsgBox("Do you wish to overwrite the previous Issue Report file for " & country & "?", vbYesNo, "Existing File -")
        If answer = vbYes Then
            GoTo here:
        ElseIf answer = vbNo Then
            issuesWB.Close False
        End If
    End If

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        ws.Activate
        ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
        ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 1
        Range("A1").Select
    Next ws

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Run").Activate

    'Unload RepIssForm

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub```
````

Comment: I also wanted to say that I'm getting out of memory issues at certain points as well using the same code. That could be related to my crappy work rig, but if someone has pointers on keeping that from occurring with the same code, I'd be very grateful.

Comment: You get an automation error very likely because you use the default instance of your user form `GetIssForm` and you have an `Unload GetIssForm` in your code.

Comment: how do I fix that then? What would a non-default instance of that be? I unload the userform once I've passed the combobox into the variable memory. Is that not correct?

Comment: Reading suggestions [Userforms](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-user-forms-1/), [Default Instance](https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/userforms_advanced_tips.html), [Userform1.show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)